# Is there a way to cancel an awaiting POST request in a Node.js environment?

Tags: node.js, heroku, memory-leaks, request, puppeteer

Right now, my client application has a button that sends a POST request when it is clicked. The request is sent to a server that I've deployed on Heroku that has a Postgres database. When I click the button once, it takes ~3-4 seconds for the request to be fully processed as the function has a lot of awaits in it. When I click the button very fast however, I end up getting a bunch of the following:

```
2021-05-13T15:49:53.801769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/featuresNearMe" host=sparrow-testing.herokuapp.com request_id=b03523d9-acb0-4140-832f-7af56fbeee4c fwd="143.229.250.40" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-05-13T15:49:54.230124+00:00 app[web.1]: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
2021-05-13T15:49:54.230126+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111
2021-05-13T15:49:54.242812+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2021-05-13T15:49:54.242813+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-05-13T15:49:54.242879+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2021-05-13T15:49:54.242920+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2021-05-13T15:49:54.242952+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

My Puppeteer awaits also throw an error:

```
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942751+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942752+00:00 app[web.1]: [0513/154954.311863:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(135)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942753+00:00 app[web.1]: [0513/154954.311951:FATAL:memory_dump_manager.cc(282)] Check failed: started.
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942753+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x564866efa259 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942754+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 0x564866e669e3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942754+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 0x564866e77610 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942754+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 0x564866e780ce logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942755+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 0x564866f2dde3 base::trace_event::MemoryDumpManager::GetOrCreateBgTaskRunnerLocked()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942755+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 0x564866f2dd32 base::trace_event::MemoryDumpManager::GetDumpThreadTaskRunner()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942755+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 0x5648654cdf31 content::InitializeBrowserMemoryInstrumentationClient()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942756+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 0x564866e06fce content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunBrowser()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942756+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 0x564866e06c5d content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942756+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 0x564866e0429d content::RunContentProcess()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942757+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 0x564866e04c3d content::ContentMain()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942757+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 0x564866e60c29 headless::HeadlessBrowserMain()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942757+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 0x564866e6093a headless::HeadlessShellMain()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942757+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 0x564863e913e1 ChromeMain
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942758+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 0x7fcf7d9460b3 __libc_start_main
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942758+00:00 app[web.1]: #15 0x564863e9122a _start
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942758+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942758+00:00 app[web.1]: Received signal 6
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942759+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x564866efa259 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942759+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 0x564866e669e3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942759+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 0x564866ef9e00 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942760+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 0x7fcf7f2d03c0 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so+0x153bf)
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942760+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 0x7fcf7d96518b gsignal
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942760+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 0x7fcf7d944859 abort
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942760+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 0x564866ef9425 base::debug::BreakDebugger()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942760+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 0x564866e77a37 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942761+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 0x564866e780ce logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942761+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 0x564866f2dde3 base::trace_event::MemoryDumpManager::GetOrCreateBgTaskRunnerLocked()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942781+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 0x564866f2dd32 base::trace_event::MemoryDumpManager::GetDumpThreadTaskRunner()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942782+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 0x5648654cdf31 content::InitializeBrowserMemoryInstrumentationClient()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942782+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 0x564866e06fce content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunBrowser()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942782+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 0x564866e06c5d content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942782+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 0x564866e0429d content::RunContentProcess()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942783+00:00 app[web.1]: #15 0x564866e04c3d content::ContentMain()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942783+00:00 app[web.1]: #16 0x564866e60c29 headless::HeadlessBrowserMain()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942783+00:00 app[web.1]: #17 0x564866e6093a headless::HeadlessShellMain()
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942783+00:00 app[web.1]: #18 0x564863e913e1 ChromeMain
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942784+00:00 app[web.1]: #19 0x7fcf7d9460b3 __libc_start_main
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942784+00:00 app[web.1]: #20 0x564863e9122a _start
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942784+00:00 app[web.1]: r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 00007ffefdad4510 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942784+00:00 app[web.1]: r12: 0000025400304000 r13: 00007ffefdad4770 r14: 0000025400304010 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942784+00:00 app[web.1]: di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007ffefdad4510  bp: 00007ffefdad4760  bx: 00007fcf7c5a8500
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942784+00:00 app[web.1]: dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007fcf7d96518b  sp: 00007ffefdad4510
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942785+00:00 app[web.1]: ip: 00007fcf7d96518b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 630a000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942785+00:00 app[web.1]: trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942785+00:00 app[web.1]: [end of stack trace]
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942785+00:00 app[web.1]: Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942785+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942785+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942786+00:00 app[web.1]: TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942786+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942786+00:00 app[web.1]: at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:194:20)
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942786+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:185:79)
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942786+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:327:22)
2021-05-13T15:49:54.942787+00:00 app[web.1]: at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
```

My question is the following: Is there a way to cancel incoming requests if there is already one being processed? (AKA have the following clicks on the button that send the POST requests NOT register). Alternatively, is there a way to cancel requests that are currently processing?

Finally, is that Puppeteer error thrown because the url that I'm scraping from (Google) is detecting it's a bot opening the browser so it shuts down requests for a limited time? (I think this is what's causing it, but I'm not sure).

I've implemented a pool that releases the client at the end of the function, because I thought that might be causing the memory leak but it appears that's not the problem, so I'm wondering if this could be, thanks!

Comment: I'm confused here.  At first I thought you just had your own client application talking to your own nodejs server and the usual solution is to "debounce" the submit button so the end-user can't press it twice before you've finished processing it.  Then, you mention Puppeteer which leads me to be all confused.  Are you running Puppeteer on someone else's front-end?  To someone else's backend?  I'm totally confused.

Comment: ***Is there a way to cancel incoming requests if there is already one being processed?***  Cancel from where?  On your server?  If so, sure you could code that.  You'd have to keep a client-specific state machine (probably in a server-side user session) that keeps track of what you are currently processing and can abort (send back an immediate error or response) for any incoming connection that is a duplicate of something already in process.